# issue while accessing secure web services in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, security

I am using this as web service reference

```
http://<hostname>:8080/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService?wsdl"
```

but now I have to use secure one using ssl such as

```
**https:**//<hostname>/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService?wsdl"
```

this one should use the port 443 by default

I've tried to use it as it is but it give no result once I communicate in my code 
this what I use normally

```
USD_WebService wsUSD = new USD_WebService();
string username = "user name";
string password = "Password";
int sid = wsUSD.login(username, password);
userhandle = wsUSD.getHandleForUserid(sid, username);
```

but now am not able to get even the sid.

is it a problem from the certificate side or it is network authentication problem?

I received the below exceptions

system.net.webexception unable to connect to the remote server system.net.sockets.socketexception
a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond :80

Comment: Please change your title.  People coming to your question from Google are going to think they will be learning how to access secure web services from C#, and are going to be disappointed.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when attempting to call `.login` or another function?  If so, could you post some exception information?  That should help give some direction to the cause of the error.

Comment: system.net.webexception unable to connect to the remote server system.net.sockets.socketexception
a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <hostname>:80

Comment: Could you also post what's in the app.config file?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue 
after going through the app.config as jmgardn2 replied in his comment.

I found that whenever I add the secure link to web reference it will not reflect in the config file with correct link. simply it will remove the s from https and I relay don't know why the visual studio removed it see as below

```
<app.Properties.Settings>

        <value>http://<hostname>/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService</value>
</app.Properties.Settings>
```

I am 100% sure that I added the secure web reference and when I changed it back to this

```
<value>https://<hostname>/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService</value>
```

it worked perfectly,